A Potential supervisor has suggested to contact two other professors as he is resigning from the University. He has cc the professors too in the mail
The Mail sent back by potential supervisor  mentioned me to contact this new suggested person 1 or new suggested person 2? He has also forwarded both the professors the mail. Will it be ok to connect with both of them

Be cautious, please! But yes, it was an introduction. Best of luck!

It sounds like you got an introduction. Refer to the first prof, briefly introduce yourself and make a brief, polite case as to what you are looking for. Brevity is your ace, profs are busy.

I assume that the potential supervisor is a person at a university that you are attending and that you approached. In this case, you should follow up on these leads if they appear to you to be a good fit. If you are asking whether you can contact both, it is natural for a student to look at several people and there is nothing unusual with contacting more than one.
